# How do you implement a choice in a state machine in Qt?

Tags: qt, qstatemachine

Imagine a part of your state machine looks like this:

[image]

How do you properly implement the choice part in Qt? I know there are [guarded transitions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/statemachine-api.html#events-transitions-and-guards), but that would mean that I need to:

- Create a subclass of a [QAbstractTransition](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttransition.html) which accepts e.g. an `std::function<bool()>` and a flag which determines if the transition happens when that boolean result is true, or when it is false
- Create two instances of this class with the same boolean function, but opposite transition guards
- Add two transitions from `S1` using these two instances.

That approach seems kind of clumsy and error prone for something as simple as a choice.
Is there a more maintainable approach to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

License Notice:

Alternatively to the [default StackOverflow license](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) you are hereby allowed to use this code through the [MIT License](https://mit-license.org/).

I've created a `BooleanChoiceTransition` class with a constructor like this (might contain errors, the code is not on this machine, so I typed it by heart):

```
BooleanChoiceTransition::BooleanChoiceTransition(std::function<bool()> choiceFunc, QState* targetForTrueCase, QState* targetForFalseCase)
  : QState{}
{
    this->addTransition(this, &BooleanChoiceTransition::transitionToTrueTarget, targetForTrueCase);
    this->addTransition(this, &BooleanChoiceTransition::transitionToFalseTarget, targetForFalseCase);
    (void)QObject::connect(this, &QAbstractState::entered, [this]() {
        if(choiceFunc())
        {
            emit transitionToTrueTarget();
        }
        else
        {
            emit transitionToFalseTarget();
        }
    });
}
```

with `transitionToTrueTarget` and `transitionToFalseTarget` being signals of course.

For the case of the example in the question, the class can be used like so:

```
auto choiceState = new BooleanChoiceTransition([this](){ return _someConditionFullfilled; }, s2, s3);
s1->addTransition(this, &MyClass::someTrigger, choiceState);
```

Since `BooleanChoiceTransition` is a `QState`, this can even be nested easily:

```
auto outerChoiceState = new BooleanChoiceTransition([this](){ return _someOtherConditionFullfilled; }, s4, choiceState);
```